# How to put button on the bottom right and above everything?

Tags: javascript, css, button

Now I have a button created with bootstrap that existing on the top of the page.[image: This]

And I wonder, how can I move it to the right bottom and remove all this white lines around it. I have to create it within js code.

```
    var button='<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data placement="bottom">Click here</button>&nbsp;';
    $("#tree-container").append(button);
```

I'd like to have it like this: [image]

upd: I'm using in on flask, so there is only one line of meaningful html code:

```
      <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='MyTree.js')}}"></script>
```

Other are styles and lib downloads

Comment: Please, post the HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.btn.btn-success {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

Comment: how should I connect this with my button variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with CSS absolute positioning

Answer (score 0):

To get the button to always be in the bottom right corner, ake a look at the [fixed position using css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

For it to always display above other elements, set the z-index property to be higher than all the elements on the page. [z-index Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)